# Regarding VF page to custom settings

Tags: visualforce, controller, customsetting

Req: I have a command button on VF page.

When i click on it then a popup window needs to open (That can be achievable). When we add to some values those need to get saved into custom settings and those need to be available in a multi-select picklist on same page.

1. Need to save into custom settings from visualforce page.
2. Those values needs to get refresh from  custom settings to that mulitselect picklist field on same VF page.

Any Suggestions or any sample codes regarding above two points please provide me.

```
/***************VF page******************************/
<apex:page controller="Sample_Groups" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Groups}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>       
         </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>


/*********************** Controller********************************/
public with sharing class Sample_Groups{

    public List<Group_Details__c> Groups{get;set;}

    public InvestorGroups()
    {
        Map<String,Group_Details__c> allGroups = Investor_Details__c.getAll();
        Groups = allGroups.values();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Some questions: Where are you inputting the new value? (Is there an input inputfield on the VF page?) And is your multiselect field a field on an object? Or is it only to be used in this VF page?

Comment: Yes.You are correct.new values need to save into custom settings and  mullti-select pick list from object field.

Comment: Not sure if saving it into both the custom setting and the multi-select picklist field is a good idea.. Do you really need the 2nd option?

Comment: Yes I need second functionality.I am trying as follows.

Comment: public List<SelectOption> getMyOptions(){
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();     
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = customobject__c.custommultiselect__c.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry entry : picklistEntries){options.add(new SelectOption(entry.getValue(),entry.getLabel()));
}for(Investor_Details__c setting : Investor_Details__c.getAll().values()){
options.add(new SelectOption(setting.name, setting.name));
}return options;

Comment: <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}"> <apex:selectOptions value="{!MyOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>                                          By this functionality i am getting just pick list.But i need as multiselect picklist

Comment: Add this: <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="true">     If multiselect is true, the value attribute must be of type String[] or a List of strings.

Comment: It's just for select as multiple values.Not for Multiselect picklist view.

Comment: multiselect="true" is for selecting multivalues.Not for multiselect picklist view.

Comment: OK. So do you want to just fill the multiselect on this visualforce page, or do you also want to update the selectable values on a multiselect custom field on an object? In other words: where/how will you store the actual values selected in the multiselect?

Comment: Just i want a multiselect picklist look and nature on my visualforce page after combining.Now it is showing just picklist nature and look

Comment: there's a nice component by Pat Patterson that does just that: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html

Comment: yes you are correct.But there is no component definition.So we need to define component and use that component into my page.Is there any simple way for that look and feel?

Comment: nope no simple way. It has to be built all from scratch. You could copy the source code from github, as stated by Pat.

Answer (score 1):

Custom setting objects can be created in apex just like a custom object.

```
setting_name__c settings = setting_name__c.getInstance();
```

Depending on they type of setting you are using you would need a different method to receive it. See: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

Variables(fields) can then be set using standard functionality, ie:

```
settings.fieldName = localVar;
```

Combining this you can achieve something like:

```
public with sharing class Sample_Groups{

public List<Group_Details__c> Groups{get;set;}
public String localVar{get;set;}

public InvestorGroups()
{
    setting_name__c settings = setting_name__c.getInstance();

    //localVar = settings.fieldName 
    //picklistvalues = settings.values;

    Map<String,Group_Details__c> allGroups = Investor_Details__c.getAll();
    Groups = allGroups.values();
} 

public PageReference applySettings(){

    settings.fieldName = localVar;

     try{
        update settings;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm,
        'Settings Updated: '));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,
        'Failed to update settings' );
    }

    return null;
}}
```

Depending on what you want in the visualforce page you'll probably have an input field that uses {!localVar} to input the new value to save. You can get the values from the settings object to fill in the pick list field pretty easily as well, look into Select List and Select Options. Depending on how the Custom Setting is set up you'll have to use the values stored to create selectOption objects and add them to a List to populate the visualforce page.